# Why do my objects become null on returning to my previous Activity

Tags: android, google-maps, nullpointerexception, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I have two activities Suppose A and B;

**activity A** has several objects of View [`TextView`, `TabView`, `ListView` etc]:

I fire an Intent using `startActivityForResult` and go to **activity B**

then i do my computation as required in **activity B** and return back to **activity A** by `setRuslt` and then `finish();`

on returning to my **onActivityResult** i work according to the result sent from **activity B**;

*Everything above works perfectly fine.[During testing]*

But when i have deployed my application I am facing crashes [unexpected Nullpointer exception]

-> In some cases ListView inside my onResume method is null;

-> In some cases my tabView is null;

-> In some cases my database object instance is null;

am I missing any important step of the activity lifecycle. It works fine while in testing.

**Please Note: I have map Views on both the activities**

Please help.
Thank you in advance.

HERE's AN STACK TRACE

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at in.abmulani.thisway.MainActivity.onKeyDown(MainActivity.java:511)
at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2719)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2419)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:190)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverKeyEventPostIme(ViewRootImpl.java:4150)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleImeFinishedEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4112)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:3292)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
```

Comment: Please show some code of how you navigate between activities

Comment: Log cat is the crash report! and it points to my listView object [NullPointer] and the amount of null pointer that is encountered will force to post my entire code[thatz not possible dude]

Comment: It never occurs during testing i have 6 devices and works fine in those device. But i dont know from where do they occur after deploying on the playstore

Comment: @AabidMulani dude..okay! crash report then! should be used to figure out the first crash it reports, atleast that gives you a starting point. if the "amount of null pointer that is encountered..." , is so much then the code doesn't look too good and testing has been considering static cases only. See if you can figure the first NPE and post l-o-c related to that. It may help, to start with

Comment: @AabidMulani which is line no.511 in MainActivity.java ?

Comment: tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

Comment: and i dont know why is it null at that point. [yes, its called immediately after onActivityResult]

Comment: inspect the value of tabHost and its declaration in activity

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the data in the onActivityResult is null.Have you checked it?

And if your activity has a LaunchMode of **SingleInstance**,the onActivityResult will be invoked by android as soon as you starActivityForResult.Make sure your activity is not a SingleInstance activity.

Last, what you have done in the onResume method?

Comment: No SingleInstance, i have modified nothing in the manifest for the launchMode

Comment: Maybe the data object return to your onActivityResult is null,and you should check why the listview got a NullPointerException(data source is updated to a null,or some other errors?)

Comment: it fine if the data object returned is null [I am checking for null condition], but the listView object is pointed as Null not my data. why is that?

Comment: Do i need to use these methods [I am not sure, Never used them]: **onSaveInstanceState** **onRestoreInstanceState**

Comment: I think your should show some code of your logcat or source.

Comment: Updated my question!...This is one of the crash

Comment: Maybe onSaveInstanceState can really solve your problem.Because you said nothing occurs when you test it.I think this problem maybe occurred in some cheap phones that not have enough memory.when you do a startActivityForResult,your activity is in background,it can be destroy by adnroid because of low memory currently.

Comment: Please provide some resource of how to use onSaveInstanceState; and btw Nexus S is one of the device which is facing the crash

Comment: You should find which data is the reason for the problem,then put it in the savedInstanceState(which is a bundle,can putSerializable) and restore it in onRestoreInstanceState.The most important is:how to find this data object.